# sql results, How to count points for duplicate names for each name in php code

Tags: php, sql, points

i have sql table in this website

[Nourena](https://nourena.com/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AD%D8%B5%D8%A7%D8%A6%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%86%D9%87%D8%A7%D8%A6%D9%8A%D8%A9/)

NOTE : i want to edit this php code

```html
<?php 

// make connecion
mysql_connect('host', 'host user', '');

// Select Database
mysql_select_db ('database name');

$sql="SELECT * FROM database_name";

$records=mysql_query($sql);



?>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>الاحصائيات النهائية لمسابقة اكتوبر</title>
</head>

<body>

<table>
    
   <tr>
    <th style="width: 40px;">Pos.</th>
    <th style="">Name</th>
    <th style="width: 60px;">Points</th>
   <tr>
<?php 

 while($database_name=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)) {
  
  echo "<tr>"; 
  
  echo "<td>".$database_name[toplist_id]."</td>"; 
  
  echo "<td>".$database_name[name]."</td>";
  
  echo "<td>".$database_name[points]."</td>";
  
  echo "</tr>"; 
  
  
  }// End While

?>               
           
                  
 </table>

</body>
</html>

<?php 

?>
```

as you see in the table i have duplicate names like beltagy and points for this name.

i want to count points for each name and show name with out duplicate.

also want to rank names like ".pos " in the table According to the most on the receipt of a number of points for each name

now i would like to show this table like this

```
.pos    name      points

  1     beltagy     9
  2     test        8
```

please i am newbie and need this quickly , and so sorry for little english

Comment: please i need help , i can not do this until now and the bottom answer not working with me , thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alter your query to this:

```
$sql="SELECT toplist_id, name, SUM(points) as totalPoints
      FROM database_name
      GROUP BY name
      ORDER BY SUM(points) as totalPoint DESC";
```

** 'database_name' should actually be the table name, but you have used 'database_name' in your original question.

Comment: Maggs , thanks for your help but sorry not working , you can see the error on the link above in my question

Comment: What is the name of your database table?

Comment: database table name:  wp_wp_pro_quiz_toplist

Comment: database table name:  wp_wp_pro_quiz_toplist  , i already changed database_name to wp_wp_pro_quiz_toplist , but gave me error